# Excel VBA not giving error messages in debug mode

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I am writing some Macros in Excel and everything was going very well.

At the moment, everything is still sort-of working, but I've encountered a strange problem and I can't find any threads about it.

When the program encounters a code error, such as type mismatch or wrong references (examples below), it does not break the code at the culprit line, but just aborts the entire macro and ends it peacefully with no messages or anything.

It's like I accidentally changed a setting or something that is now causing the debugger to not bug me with debug messages.

Please help! I would like my error messages and "just in time" breaks back!

```
Dim Margin As Double

If COS <> 0 Then
  Margin = Round((SALES - COS) / COS * 100, 2)
Else
  Margin = "???"
End If
```

or like a wrong reference:

```
Dim that_cell as string
that_cell = "5"
Range(that_cell).Select
```

Thanks,

Pieka

Comment: No error messages at all seems strange. Did you check the Error Trapping option (Tools-Options, tab "General" in the VBE)?

Comment: I've seen this happen in UDF's before, errors won't raise the function just returns an error value instead. Otherwise @mehow's solution should help.

Comment: no more mehow comment. I'm not seeing the output in SO about not seeing the output in VBA.

Answer (score 4):

I've just come across this same issue over the past few days.  I've spent copious amounts of time extending Access with VBA and never had an issue quite like this.  However, I am aware of the Error trapping options and when to use each option.  SO, to my chagrin, **to fix this error** I had to do the unintuitive opposite of what mehow suggested.  I actually changed the Error Trapping option to 'Break on All Errors.'  All of sudden, I get the debugging options I'm used to getting.

Now, obviously, once you take a piece of code into production, you'll need to choose 'Break on Unhandled Errors' (and pray you've trapped and planned for every concievalbe error.....).

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem that was caused by me trying to assign a default value of 0 to an optional range object:

```
Function test(rng1 as Range, Optional rng2 = 0)
    test = "Never gets to this line"
End Function
```

The function returns a `#VALUE` error without letting you enter debug mode to find out that it is the function declaration line causing the error.

I know it's a rookie error to try and assign a value to a range object, but if anyone else is struggling to enter debug mode, it might be because you are incorrectly assigning values to objects in your parameter list.